# MVC Responsibilities

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

In a ModelViewController architecture, who is responsible for the handling of drag & drop of items, picking, selection, double click, etc? Think of a drawing tool. And what about in a 3d app where you can move the camera, pick up and move objects...?

Also, I've read that MVC belongs to the presentation layer, and that the model is not the database. However, outside the web context, is it always like this? Imagine a simpler context, like a windows Qt app, where the data is stored as simple XML files, which are deserialized into memory when opened by the app.

Thanks!

Comment: Q: _Who is responsible for the handling of drag & drop of items, picking, selection, double click, etc_ A: The view.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Qt framework proposes Model/View, not Model/View/Controller. So, database is not included in the pattern. The model is responsible for communication with 'Data' block:

[image]

Drag and drops, as well as selections, are handled by View widgets, and model only implements business logic. It is worth reading [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) to understand better how Qt suppose to use Model/View pattern.